# Android subscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList returns null in AAOS 10 but works in AAOS 12

Tags: android, telephonymanager, android-subscriptionmanager

When i pair an iPhone to a device running AAOS12, and I enable "Show Notifications" on the iPhone's bluetooth connection to the device, I am able to see an entry in the list returned by `SubscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList()`. However, the same test on the same device running AAOS10, always returns a null list when `SubscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList()` is called. Trying to figure out why this doesn't work in AAOS 10.

Paired iPhone to device running AAOS10, and then run application that calls `SubscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList()`.